# How do I send test Eth from one EOA to another on the Rinkeby testnet using Infura?

Tags: transactions, javascript, testnets, pending-transactions, sendsignedtransaction

I am trying to check if I am able to send one test ether from one Wallet (Wallet 2) to another Wallet (Wallet 1) using JavaScript. I tried to do this using the codes below but for some reason, this is not working with me and I do not understand the error. I am new to this, so please bear with me as I am trying to introduce my code.

First of all I start as simple as this.

Please note that in order to perform this code you will need to create your own 1. Infura API key, 2. Mnemonic Phrase of Wallet 1 (which contains no test ether), 3. The private key of Wallet 2 (which contain 15 test Ether).

```
// Get references to the modules (or the module content) that we need
const ethers = require('ethers');

// Get references to the modules (or the module content) that we need
var Web3 = require('web3');

// Use your Project ID Infura API using the rinkeby testnet
const Project_ID_Infura = '';

// This represent the API which is important to get connected to the provider (i.e. the blockchain testnet)
// This apikey is recieved from Infura which I did a new project to get the API key!
const apiKey = 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/' + Project_ID_Infura;

// This represent the API which is important to get connected to the provider (i.e. the blockchain testnet)
// This apikey is recieved from Infura which I did a new project to get the API key!
const apiKey = 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/' + Project_ID_Infura;

// Creating a new instance of the Web3 and ensuring that it is connected to the rinkeby testnet using Infura API
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(apiKey));

var util = require('ethereumjs-util');

// Introducing the same mnemonic phrase as the pre-recorded lecture of this course
const Mnemonic_Phrase = 'Create your own Mnemonic';

// Create a Wallet from a Mnemonic phrase
const Wallet_1 = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(Mnemonic_Phrase);

var Private_key_Wallet_2 = '0xc7fdadfda...';

// Creating a Wallet based on private key!
const Wallet_2 = new ethers.Wallet(Private_key_Wallet_2);

// Let us create a function that enables us to get the money from a defined wallet
async function Check_balance(wallet) {
  Ballance_wallet = await web3.eth.getBalance(wallet.address);
  Ballance_wallet = web3.utils.fromWei(Ballance_wallet, 'ether');
  return Ballance_wallet;
}

// Creating transaction with variable inputs

function tx_vriable_input(gasPrice_1, gasLimit_1, to_wallet) {
  // Creating a transaction by sending from an EOA to another!
  var TxData = {
    nonce: 1,
    gasPrice: gasPrice_1,
    gasLimit: gasLimit_1,
    to: to_wallet.address,
    value: 1,
  };
  return TxData;
}

async function test1() {
  Balance_Wallet_1 = await Check_balance(Wallet_1);
  Balance_Wallet_2 = await Check_balance(Wallet_2);
  console.log('This is the balance of the Wallet 1: ', Balance_Wallet_1); // 0
  console.log('This is the balance of the Wallet 2: ', Balance_Wallet_2); //18.751

  // Creating a transaction
  // Get the current gas price
  Current_gas_price = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
  // Do some modification to incentivise the miner to mine your transaction
  Acceptable_gas_price = Number.parseInt(Current_gas_price) * 1.4;

  // Get the latest average gas limit of the latest block
  var block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  number_of_transactions_per_latest_block = block.transactions.length;
  gas_limit_of_all_the_block = block.gasLimit;
  average_gas_limit_per_transaction =
    gas_limit_of_all_the_block / number_of_transactions_per_latest_block;
  // console.log('Hello ', average_gas_limit_per_transaction);

  // Get the nonce of the wallet
  let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(Wallet_2.address);
  console.log('Nonce of Wallet 2: ', nonce + 1);

  // Import the transaction method
  const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

  tx_data = tx_vriable_input(
    Acceptable_gas_price,
    average_gas_limit_per_transaction,
    Wallet_1
  );
  console.log(tx_data);
  // Create the first transaction
  var first_tx1 = new EthereumTx(tx_data, { chain: 'rinkeby' });

  console.log('Before Signing');

  // Now we need to sign this contract using Wallet 2 private key
  var Private_key_to_sign_Wallet_2 = new Buffer.from(
    Wallet_2.privateKey.replace('0x', ''),
    'hex'
  );

  // Sign first_tx1 transaction
  first_tx1.sign(Private_key_to_sign_Wallet_2);
  console.log('After Signing');

  // Also known as raw transaction in the Bitcoin blockchain framework!
  serializedTx = first_tx1.serialize();

  signedTransaction = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction).then(receipt => {
    console.log('receipt', receipt);
    this.setState({ rawReceipt: receipt });
  });

  Balance_Wallet_1_new = await Check_balance(Wallet_1);
  console.log('The new balance of Wallet 1 is: ', Balance_Wallet_1_new);
}

test1();
```

This will give some understanding of my code whereby I failed to do the simple task of sending test Ether from one EOA (Wallet 2) to another EOA (Wallet 1). Remember that I took into account most of the things I have seen online but if there is something I am not aware of please let me be aware of it.

Comment: The transaction data has `nonce: 1` hardcoded it should be `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)` instead.

Comment: @Ismael that still did not work! :S the nonce anyway is one